# Geo Service wfs : How call by range?

Tags: geoserver

I'm using the API WFS from the French Government to get geographical data. This API use OGC. (https://geoservices.ign.fr/documentation/donnees-ressources-wfs.html)

*"IRIS2000" is an acronym which stood for "Islands Grouped for Statistical Information" and which referred to the target size of 2,000 inhabitants per elementary mesh. It is the basic building block for the dissemination of infra-municipal data.*

I would like to get all Iris2000 data, but the API deliver 1000 objects maximum by request.
They are 49404 differents Iris2000 and I don't find the range parameter.

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WFS is a public international standard, check the specification at http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/09-025r2/09-025r2.html.

I believe you are looking for paged request support, that is, the startIndex and count parameters: http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/09-025r2/09-025r2.html#50

Comment: I didn't undestand that used a public international standard, Thank you ! :)